# Perl regex to replace a underscore or forward slash with a dash

Tags: regex, perl

While there are several regex examples here showing the many variations, simply I just want to use regex in Perl to search 2 different strings with one string as an underscore(_) and the other string as a forward slash (/) and replace each string with a hyphen (-) plus string.  I am using the delimiter backslash, however it is the incorrect output.

```
Input:          Output:
_APPLE          -APPLE
/APPLE          -APPLE
```

Here is my code:

```
$string1 =~ s/\_\/APPLE/-APPLE
$string2 =~ s/\/\/APPLE/-APPLE
```

Comment: what is the word contains an underscore but does not contain a forward slash? What do you mean by saying that your delimiter is a backslash? Can you show it in your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has an extra (escaped) `/` and would match strings with `_/` (and `//` in the second case). That is not in your data, which has either `_` or `/`, not both.

Also, there is no need to escape the `_`, and neither the `/` if it is not the delimiter.

To match either of a few characters the cleanest and most efficient is the *character class*

```
$string =~ s{[_/](\w+)}{-$1};
```

The *alternation* also works here

```
$string =~ s{(?:_|/)(\w+)}{-$1};
```

but it is more suitable when possibilities to match have more characters (`word|another`).

There are quite a few assumptions here, given how little is specified in the question.  For one, `\w` also matches digits and `_` along with letters. If you clarify the requirements I'll edit as needed.

I assume that the missing closing delimiter, needed for the code to compile, is a typo in posting.

Comment: My string has an underscore and a forward slash.  If it has an underscore or forward slash, then match with a hyphen.

Comment: @Minimalist  I don't understand that.  (1) Your "_Input_" shows _either_ `_` _or_ `/`.  (2) The first sentence in your comment says that it's both, while the second sentence says that it's either.

Comment: Apologize.  They are two separate strings, but the outcome is the same, a hyphen.

Comment: Ah, OK; so it can be a `_` (in some strings), or it can be a `/` (in some other strings).  That's what I assumed in this answer, and it works for that.  The `$string` in my answer can be either.

Comment: It's better to replace the non-capturing group with a character class `[_/]`. Also we should note that current regex matches `/_APPLE` too which may not be desirable.

Comment: @revo  Good points, added another regex and a comment, thank you. I don't see that the character class is "_better_" but it is surely nicer here.

Comment: An alternation provides engine with two different paths at a point. Engine chooses one to approach then chooses the other one if previous path fails to match. So it is possible for an engine to take an extra step depending on input string. Although it's one extra step, it costs since it is not only one extra step. Engine may go much further then needs a backtrack. So we are not sure about how many steps engine should take to find a successful match. Having that said, the best practice would be using a `[..]` whenever we are doing sth like `(X|Y|..)`. So we could say it's both better and nicer.

Comment: @revo Well, yes. But with the character class the engine also tries the first character first and then has to go back, no? Or is character class processed differently?

Comment: Engines implement character classes differently. It's like looking for `x` among a list of characters `[a,b,c..]`. It's fast and a failure / match happens earlier. On the other hand groups couldn't be treated as a list of characters since they are supposed to enclose large expressions. It means engine should go with each path till a failure or success and it takes much more time.

Comment: @revo Alright, thank you; I don't know how they are implemented.  Edited

Comment: @zdim.  Exactly.  Clean and Efficient.  Works well in my code.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Minimalist Thank you for feedback. Let me know if questions pop up